# Export xls with dates from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: export, sqldeveloper

Does anyone know how I can export an excel file from SQL developer with the fields formatted correctly? In particular the date and time columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a setting for this in SQL Developer, but you can transform your dates into an Excel-readable Serial Date Format. I found how to do this [here](http://www.jasonsdevelopercorner.com/?p=209).

If you don't want to create a new function (this is a one-off query, you need to get data from a database with read-only access), the format string is essentially

```
((trunc(p_date) + v_date_differential) – (TO_DATE(’01-JAN-1900′,’DD-MON-YYYY’)-1))
```

where `p_date` is the date field, and `v_date_differential` is `1` if the date is after 1/1/1900, 0 if not.